# How to most effectively learn IOS development?

Tags: ios

I have a decent amount of programming experience, and I just do not know where to start to learn this.

I've done the tutorials on apple's site, and looked at some other examples, but there is just so much stuff you need to know, that I'm feeling kind of lost.

I understand the whole MVC thing, I understand and know objective c, I just know all the general stuff, but when writing an app I just miss a lot of knowledge and I'm constantly unsure about how to do certain things.

Is it just a matter of keep going at it? Are there any really good books? Any really good online resources?

And again: it's really about just getting to know the ins and outs of all the frameworks and different objects and stuff

Comment: Oh boy, there is a lot of resources:

 1. Paul Hegarty's iTunesU course from Stanford. [Link here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/)
 2. [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com) for sure
 3. [Ray Wenderlich website](http://www.raywenderlich.com)
 4. [objc.io](http://www.objc.io)
 5. And of course [NSScreencast](http://nsscreencast.com)

Don't forget to visit [Apple Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com) which is great!!

You can buy books (if you like) but you must remember that they can get old pretty soon.

Comment: Those itunes things are from 2011, isn't that too old?

Comment: @user2520938 You have new Stanford courses too. Just search for iPhone development in iTunes University ;)

Comment: @user2520938 Here you go: https://itunes.apple.com/si/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Answer (score 7):

For someone in your position, the two words you need to know are [Ray](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) and [Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/).

Answer (score 4):

For beginners I would really recommend to watch **Paul Hegarty's** *Stanford iPhone development courses*.

See:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774?mt=10

His courses are one of the most clear and effective courses I've ever seen.

**EDIT**:

New (iOS 7 courses):
https://itunes.apple.com/si/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Answer (score 1):

Watch few intro videos, read few intro articles. Plenty of them online. And build something. Repeat.